# Серийный порт в C# - получение данных, предотвращение потери данных - лучшие практики?

Tags: c#, serial, rs232, uart

Добрый день,

Не первый раз использую событие SerialPort.DataReceived, но первый раз задумался над тем как его правильно использовать и что-же под ним скрыто.
На данный момент использую следующий алгоритм (для того, что-бы избежать межпотоковых ошибок):

1. Запуск таймера на период 10-50 мсек.
   1.1. В событии Tick данные из статической переменной присваиваются нужным переменным. Это все происходит только если выставлен флаг, что можно проверять эту статическую переменную. После этого флаг на разрешение проверки обнуляется.
2. Срабатывание события DataReceived.
   2.1 Если флаг проверки статической переменной выставлен - команда на повторную передачу данных через 10 мсек и выход из обработчика.
   В обратном случае:
3. Считывание данных из бафера порта до конца строки (ReadLine) в статическую переменную.
4. Выставление флага на проверку статической переменной.

**Первый вопрос**:
Какие есть еще алгоритмы приема данных по серийному порту в главный поток (например использовать Invoke, но я этот метод что-то не очень понимаю) и конечно с объяснениями, если можно?

**Второй вопрос**:
Какие есть еще способы избежать потери данных, кроме того способа, что я использую (комманда на повторную передачу данных через определенное время)

**Третий вопрос**:
событие DataReceived, в какой момент оно вызывается? При приходе первого байта? При приходе EOF?

Большое спасибо!

---  ***UPDATE***   ---

Нечаяно нашел использование Invoke и почему-то сразо все понял :)
Какие еще есть варианты?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590945/how-to-display-the-data-read-in-datareceived-event-handler-of-serialport

```
public delegate void AddDataDelegate(String myString);
public AddDataDelegate myDelegate;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //...
    this.myDelegate = new AddDataDelegate(AddDataMethod);
}

public void AddDataMethod(String myString)
{
    textbox1.AppendText(myString);
}

private void mySerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
   string s= sp.ReadExisting();

   textbox1.Invoke(this.myDelegate, new Object[] {s});       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Из моей практики, DataReceived — не лучший метод для работы с последовательным портом. Я бы порекомендовал использовать `Stream` и читать из него данные асинхронно.

Допустим, последовательный порт шлёт данные следующего вида:

- 1 байт тип сообщения
- 2 байта длина строки (`n`)
- `n` байт строка
- контрольная сумма всех байт

Создаём структуру данных:

```
struct Message
{
    public byte Type;
    public string Text;
}
```

Теперь наш код выглядит как-то так:

```
port = new SerialPort(...);
port.Open();

try
{
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Message message = await ReadWholeMessage(port.BaseStream, ct);
        DispatchMessage(message); // у нас тут Rx, но вы можете
                                  // послать event или обработать на месте
    }
}
catch (OperationCanceledException) { /*нас остановили, выходим */ }
catch (ObjectDisposedException) { /* тоже остановили */ }
catch (IOException ex)
{
    // а вот это проблема, логируем и бросаем дальше
}
catch (InvalidDataException ex)
{
    // девайс вернул не то, логируем, нужна повторная инициализация
}
```

Самое интересное — `ReadWholeMessage`. Для нашего случая это выглядит как-то так:

```
async Task<Message> ReadWholeMessage(Stream stream, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var headerBytes = await StreamHelpers.ReadAsync(stream, 3, ct);
    var type = headerBytes[0];
    var stringSize = BitConverter.ToUInt16(headerBytes, 1);
    var stringBytes = await StreamHelpers.ReadAsync(stream, stringSize, ct);
    var crc = await StreamHelpers.ReadAsync(stream, 1, ct)[0];
    // тут проверка crc
    var text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(stringBytes);
    var message = new Message() { Type = type, Text = text };
    return message;
}
```

Ну и `ReadAsync`:

```
public static class StreamHelpers
{
    static public async Task<byte[]> ReadAsync(Stream s, int nBytes, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var buf = new byte[nBytes];
        var readpos = 0;
        while (readpos < nBytes)
        {
            var actuallyRead = await s.ReadAsync(buf, readpos, nBytes - readpos, ct);
            if (actuallyRead == 0)
                throw new EndOfStreamException();
            readpos += actuallyRead;
        }
        return buf;
    }
}
```

---

Обратите внимание, что логика получения сообщения получилась практически линейной, вам не нужно запоминать промежуточное состояние недочитанного сообщения.

Comment: Очень интересное решение! Спасибо огрномное!!! 
Пара вопросов. Что такое ct? Для какой версии .Net это преднозначено? await Появились после 4.5, разве нет? Так же интересна функция DispatchMessage. Это ваша функция или стандартная?

Comment: @Michael: `ct` — это `CancellationToken`, он нужен, чтобы остановить ожидание новых сообщений (например, в конце программы).

Comment: @Michael: Код для C#5+, в котором есть async/await.

Comment: @Michael: DispatchMessage должна быть функция, написанная вами. У меня она выглядит как `subject.OnNext(message);`, потому что я использую Rx для доставки сообщений тому, кому оно нужно. У вас там вполне может быть что-то другое. Роль этой функции — отослать сообщение тому, кто в нём нуждается.

Comment: Ок. Тоесть в моей функции нужно проверять не пустое ли сообщение и если пустое то выходить, правильно? Или функция сробатывает только если пришли данные на порт? Извините за, наверное, банальный вопрос, просто с async/await я не работал и еще не знаю как они функционируют.

Comment: @Michael: Да, функция срабатывает только когда прочитано целое сообщение до конца. Можно в принципе сразу выводить.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Очень интересное решение, которое я обязательно использую в программах для новой версии .Net!